# Crazy Cursor in TextBox on Table from ODBC database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am using MS Access 2013 to display data from a MySql database on another server. I have a table that uses the linked table. I have a textbox with about 100 words in it. When I click in the textbox the cursor can sometimes appear in the middle of a letter. If I try to add or delete text it appears offset from the position of the cursor. I have turned off auto-correct and tried changing the behavior of the enter key. How can I make the cursor behave normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the text contains a Tab character. The textbox doesn't show it but it messes up editing as you describe.

Copy the text into a text editor that can show invisible control characters.

Comment: Yes I think you are right there are new line characters in there that MS Access is not recognising. Any idea how to get around this problem?